# Error in variable trying to perform SlicedVectorPlot

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I have been trying to plot the normal vector over the Möbius strip, which I know I cannot do asking it to be a well-defined continuous map, nevertheless you can do it in a small region, which I am trying to illustrate, my code in the following:

```
x[u_, v_] := (1 - v Sin[u/2])*Cos[u]

y[u_, v_] := (1 - v Sin[u/2])*Sin[u]

z[u_, v_] := v Cos[u/2]

φ[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}

φu[u_, v_] := D[φ[u, v], u]

φv[u_, v_] := D[φ[u, v], v]

n[u_, v_] := 
 FullSimplify[Cross[φu[u, v], φv[u, v]]/
  Norm[Cross[φu[u, v], φv[u, v]]], -1/2 < v < 1/2 && 0 < u]

SliceVectorPlot3D[
 n[ArcTan[y1/x1], 
  z1/Cos[ArcTan[y1/x1]/2]], {z1^2 - 1 - Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] == 
   z1^2/(Cos[ArcTan[y1/x1]/
      2])^2}, {x1, -3, -1}, {y1, -3, -1}, {z1, -3, -1}]
```

but I keep getting the error message `General::ivar: z1 Sec[1/2 ArcTan[y1/x1]]` is not a valid variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Just change `SetDelayed` (:=) with `Set` (=) in your `n[u_, v_]` definition and there will be no error, but the resulting plot is empty, probably because the surface has no points in a given range of `x1, y1, z1`. The problem is that with `SetDelayed` you make differentiation with that complex variable as appeared in error message, because real computation (derivative) occurs at the call time of `n`. With `Set` you make differentiation in advance and then just substitute in complex variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful. Even so, I decided to show parametric plot of the surface and adding the arrows with Graphics 3D, It was easier that way. But you were right about the set delay comment, for that I'm thankful.